# The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first. Using Chip and ChipGroup

Tags: android

So I've defined in my layout a `ChipGroup` where I want to add multiple chips. I've created a separate entity for a general `Chip` like so:

**single_chip.xml**

```
<com.google.android.material.chip.Chip 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:id="@+id/chip"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:checkable="false"
 android:textColor="@color/light_sapphire_blue"
 android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light"
 app:chipBackgroundColor="@color/white"
 app:closeIconTint="@color/bright_sky_blue"
 app:closeIconVisible="true" />
```

So in my code when I want to add a chip in the group I do like so:

```
 View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.single_chip, null);
 Chip chip = view.findViewById(R.id.chip);

 for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : selectedFilterMap.entrySet()) {
            chip.setText(entry.getValue());
            chipGroup.addView(chip);
            chipGroup.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           }
```

But after the first chip is added  (the above code is called multiple times) I get this error:

> "The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView()
>   on the child's parent first."

Where should I call `removeView`? I've tried to add it before the `for` or after the `for` but the same error appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add it before the for loop. like this

```
 for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : selectedFilterMap.entrySet()) {
 View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.single_chip, null);
 Chip chip = view.findViewById(R.id.chip);
                chip.setText(entry.getValue());
                chipGroup.addView(chip);
                chipGroup.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
               }
```

Comment: @anMC I have modified the answer.

Comment: As you are creating a single object and set the content every time. It may be cause

Comment: Thank you. That seemed to be the problem, I don't know why I didn't think about it.